# Creating an interval using only start times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, intervals

I have call center data in a Microsoft SQL Server database, broken out only by event start times. I need to convert this to intervals, so that the start time for the next "event" for the agent is also the end time for the previous event

The table is like this:

[image]

My plan is to convert it to this:

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY AgentID ORDER BY StartTime) AS [rowID]
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT DS1.AgentID
      ,DS1.[Name]
      ,DS1.[StartTime]
      ,DS2.[StartTime]
      ,CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(SECOND, DS1.[StartTIme], DS2.[StartTime]) * 1000, 0), 114) AS [IntervalTime]
      ,DS1.[Activity]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[AgentID] = DS2.[AgentID]
    AND DS1.[rowID] = DS2.[rowID] + 1;
```

The idea is to use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to know how to join the one start period with the next one. Then we need to perform an `INNER JOIN` in order to exclude the last record (you can switch to `LEFT JOIN` in order to display it). After that, simple use `DATEDIFF` to get the differences in seconds and convert the output to the format you need.